# How to make abbreviated links to other tiddlers?

Tags: tiddlywiki, tiddlywiki5

I frequently link to another tiddler in my wiki having a particularly long name. Currently I'm using the `[[text|tiddler_name]]` syntax. I'd like to replace `tiddler_name` with an abbreviated version or shortcut rather than the full name, to make it more convenient to use. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question by accident, but if you're still looking for solutions, Tobias Beer has a macro that I've been using for years that allows you to define multiple case-insensitive alt links using the following code.

```
\define a:target()
<$list filter="[regexp:alink<regexp>limit[1]]"><$link><<target>></$link></$list>
\end

\define a:(target)
<$set name="regexp" value="\|$target$\|(?i)"><$set name="target" value="$target$"><<a:target>></$set></$set>
\end

\define alink(target) 
<<a: "$target$">> 
\end
```

https://tobibeer.github.io/tb5/#Alias%20Links

After adding the plugin to your wiki, just add a field named `alink` to the tiddler and put `|text|` as the value. You can then type `<<a: text>>` instead of `[[tiddler_name]]`.

Be aware that alink values should be lowercase and if you use something with spaces like `|your text|`, you'll need to reference it as `<<a: [[your text]]>>`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `[[|]]` syntax for that. You can define a new macro using the link widget as follows.

```
\define mylink(the_caption, text)
<$list filter="[caption[$the_caption$]]">
<$link to={{!!title}}>$text$</$link>
</$list>
\end
```

I assumed that you use the field `caption` to store a shorter name of a tiddler. Put the above code into a tiddler and tag the tiddler with `$:/tags/Macro`. To put a link using this macro, use

```
<<mylink short_name text_displayed>>
```

Basically, the macro filters all tiddlers that have the `caption=short_name`. So if there are two tiddlers having the same `caption`, two links will be displayed.